# Blending Mode Texture to PNG

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, blend-modes

I am trying to create a .png texture. In PS, the texture has two layers. One with Linear Burn and another with Soft Light. I want to merge them and save as .png to apply on different images later without using any blending mode.

But whatever I try, the final saved .png file has no transparency and looks different from the original PS file in general.

Is there any solution to create a mask in .png like this?

Comment: Blend modes depend heavily on what's under them. There are ways to handle this. ||| Depending on what you have / what you need, you could leave a solid or partially solid background beneath the layer with a blend mode. ||| You could also use other methods to achieve the same result without blend modes. Like for example: you could use levels and other layer adjustments and different opacities, instead of using blend mode(s).

Comment: I have 3 layers. First one; Linear Burn, Opacity %35 Second one; Soft Light, Opacity %85

I want an empty background beneath those layers.

But when I save as PNG, I see that blending modes does not apply.

This is the main problem.

Comment: Joonas is on the right track, but the simpler answer is "no." A blend mode relies on per-pixel software calculation based upon a simple ruleset, so unless the rendering software (such as the browser) supports it and is told to do it, it can't be done. Transparency is the only blend mode most software handles "out of the box" **without invoking special commands**. Note also, many blend modes are not commutative. In a browser you will probably need to use layers with the same blend modes and percentages.

Comment: For us to help you, I think you need to show the image and maybe the layers as well.

Answer (score 2):

A PNG file is a lossless format, but still a bit map (guess what: a map of bits), so, it is not able to carry complex informations such as the blending mode once defined.

A way to solve is to save the two layers into different textures and apply the right blending mode to each one every time you use them.

Saving an "Action" to apply the blending modes to the right layers could be an option, but it will take a lot more thinking and timing than manually setting.

I would join you in the team of those that would find it useful, but, unfortunately, it is impossible since it is not Photoshop`s "fault", it is PNG's and other image formats.